# How can I get the equivalent of foo.asInstanceOf[SomeType] in a Scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I have this in my macro impl:

```scala
def renderJsonFn(rt: RType): Expr[(Any,StringBuilder) => StringBuilder] = 

  val reflectedClassFieldInfo = ???
  val typeMaker = reflectedClassFieldInfo.fieldType.toType // (quotes: Quotes) => TypeRepr
  val fieldType = typeMaker(quotes).asType // Type[? <: AnyKind]

  '{(a:Any, sb:StringBuilder) => 

     val typedA = ?? // <<— need equivalent of a.asInstanceOf[fieldType] here

     val typedFieldValue = ${ 
       Select.unique('{ typedA }.asTerm, someFieldName).asExpr 
     }
     // This fails if I use ‘a’ —> someFieldName is not a member of Any
     // Having a:T is highly impractical—and just moves the problem.  Still need a way to typecast in a macro 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `expr: Expr[A]` and AST would typecheck if the `expr` value was `Expr[B]` (because it is of this type, just Scala for some reason doesn't know this, e.g. you constructed this expr by hand or received from somewhere as `Term`) you can use `.asExprOf`

```
expr.asExprOf[B] // requires given Type[B]
```

However if you cannot prove it in the compile time (compiler then should throw exception in the macro, after all you can check `expr.asTerm.tpe <:< TypeRepr.of[B]`) and you want to create `asInstanceOf[B]` in the generated code to perform the cast in the runtime, you can just use quoting and unquoting for that

```
'{ ${ expr }.asInstanceOf[B] } // also requires given Type[B]
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have any of this--only some basic compile-time reflected field info on a class.  The closest I can get is an TypeRepr.  I tried theTypeRepr.toType but that returned a type of Type[? <: AnyKind].  This didn't work either.   I do know the class of the field.  Can I get T from a class?

When reflecting on a class, how can I get separate types T for each field in the class?

Comment: If you have `TypeRepr` then you have a `Type` - `given Type[TypeName] = repr.asType.asInstanceOf[Type[TypeName]]`. If you don't know the name of a type, you can fake it e.g. making abstract `type FakeType` and then defining `given Type[FakeType]` or - when you have `t: Type[?]` - [using in quotes `'{ $expr.asInstanceOf[t.Underlying] }`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html#generics).